# Best C/C++ Libraries for maintaining session state in CGI application?

Tags: c, c++

I have heard of Boost and ACE as two of the well known C++ libraries. What are the other good C/C++ libraries available?

Does Boost and ACE support session management for web applications written in C/C++?

EDIT: Ok I will try to be domain specific. I am looking for a C/C++ library which could help me maintain session state for a C++ based CGI web application.

Comment: Good libraries for what?

Comment: C/C++ is not a single language, and idiomatic usage may be very different between them.  Boost and ACE are both C++ libraries.

Comment: Please narrow the title to match the "EDIT".

Answer (score 7):

When you're trying to build a web application in C++ I'd recommend [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/), a Qt-like framework for creating web applications in C++.
It handles sessions either in one process per session (when security matters) or multiple sessions per process.
You can either use the built-in webserver or use it with any webserver that supports FastCGI.

(Also, I'd recommend it over Boost.CGI as it seems to be maintained and feature-complete).

Answer (score 5):

Depends if you are talking about general purpose or domain specific libraries. For general purpose Boost is best of breed (and don't forget about the good old STL), so I don't see the point of looking for something else that will cover much of the same ground, but is not as polished. As for domain specific you'd have to specify the domain :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in C (not C++) as well, [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) (the Gnome project's utility library) provides a number of useful data structures and constructs.

Answer (score 2):

C++ has libraries for anything you could imagine, so the scope of your question is rather undefined. What interests you? Web applications, scientific programs, GUIs? Specify what you need exactly if you want a good answer.

Boost is a general-purpose library for relatively low-level things. It's rather complex and advanced though, so you should have a good grasp of C++ before you start with it. [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html) is mainly for synchronization and communication between threads/processes/applications.

If web applications is what you need, I recommend you to strongly consider the language you're picking. C++ may not be the best direction to go here, unless you have very specific constraints that force your hand.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [GTK](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/) which is good if you need to have a gui or use unicode. (although [c++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) should have better unicode support natively when the standard is complete).

Boost doesn't yet support sessions, but a [CGI library](https://launchpad.net/cgi) has been proposed which should have sessions.

If you want to use C++ for web applications, consider using [CGICC](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/)

Answer (score 2):

> Ok I will try to be domain specific. I am looking for a C/C++ library which could help me maintain session state for a C++ based CGI web application.

[CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net)?

- Example of session management: http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/tut_sessions
- Reference: http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/ref_cppcms_session_iface
- Configuration: http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/ref_config#sessions

Answer (score 1):

Poco is an excellent C++ Library with data access, xml, networking, compression and crypto all wrapped up in once nice little package.

Answer (score 1):

Boost evidently, QT for GUI (that's not clearly a library I know), [Electronic Arts Standard Template Library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html) and 
[Blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/) if you want to do scientific computation :

> Blitz++ is a C++ class library for
>   scientific computing which provides
>   performance on par with Fortran 77/90.
>
> The C++ programming language offers
>   many features useful for tackling
>   complex scientific computing problems:
>   inheritance, polymorphism, generic
>   programming, and operator overloading
>   are some of the most important.
>   Unfortunately, these advanced features
>   came with a hefty performance
>   pricetag: until recently, C++ lagged
>   behind Fortran's performance by
>   anywhere from 20% to a factor of ten.
>   As a result, the adoption of C++ for
>   scientific computing has been slow.
>
> Is there a way to soup up C++ so that
>   we can keep the advanced language
>   features but ditch the poor
>   performance? This is the goal of the
>   Blitz++ project: to develop techniques
>   which will enable C++ to rival -- and
>   in some cases even exceed -- the speed
>   of Fortran for numerical computing,
>   while preserving an object-oriented
>   interface. The Blitz++ Numerical
>   Library is being constructed as a
>   testbed for these techniques.
>
> Recent benchmarks show C++ encroaching
>   steadily on Fortran's high-performance
>   monopoly, and for some benchmarks, C++
>   is even faster than Fortran! These
>   results are being obtained not through
>   better optimizing compilers,
>   preprocessors, or language extensions,
>   but through the use of template
>   techniques. By using templates
>   cleverly, optimizations such as loop
>   fusion, unrolling, tiling, and
>   algorithm specialization can be
>   performed automatically at compile
>   time.
>
> Another goal of Blitz++ is to extend
>   the conventional dense array model to
>   incorporate new and useful features.
>   Some examples of such extensions are
>   flexible storage formats, tensor
>   notation and index placeholders.